# xpath, how to select more than one item using indices

Tags: xpath

In this query, I select the 3rd

```
//tablecontainer/table/tbody/tr/td[3]
```

How do I select both the 3rd and 4th 's?

Answer (score 1):

To get **both** the 3rd and 4th `td`s, you can use the expression:

```
//tablecontainer/table/tbody/tr/td[position() >= 3 and position() <= 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//tablecontainer/table/tbody/tr/td[position()=3 or position()=4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use XPath 2.0 you could use following trick

```
//tablecontainer/table/tbody/tr/td[position() = (1,2,4)]
```

Test `position() = (1,2,4)` means something similar as IN from SQL. Notice the brackets in `(1,2,4)` part.